# Erro de compilação gmock

Tags: c++, testes

Boa noite, estou praticado teste em c++ utilizado a biblioteca de testes da google gtest/gmock. Tudo está funcionado perfeitamente bem com o gtest, porém não consigo compilar de maneira alguma quando tento usar o gmock. Para ter certeza que não é meu código que está com problema, resolvi copiar um trecho de código usado como exemplo no [repositório](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googlemock/docs/ForDummies.md) da biblioteca.

```
    #include <gtest/gtest.h>
    #include <gmock/gmock.h>
    class Turtle {

        ~Turtle() = default;

        virtual void PenUp() = 0;

        virtual void PenDown() = 0;

        virtual void Forward(int distance) = 0;

        virtual void Turn(int degrees) = 0;

        virtual void GoTo(int x, int y) = 0;

        virtual int GetX() const = 0;

        virtual int GetY() const = 0;
    };

    class MockTurtle : public Turtle {
    public:

        MOCK_METHOD0(PenUp, void());

        MOCK_METHOD0(PenDown, void());

        MOCK_METHOD1(Forward, void(int distance));

        MOCK_METHOD1(Turn, void(int degrees));

        MOCK_METHOD2(GoTo, void(int x, int y));

        MOCK_CONST_METHOD0(GetX, int());

        MOCK_CONST_METHOD0(GetY, int());
    };
int main(int argc, char *arvg[]) {
    testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, arvg);
    testing::InitGoogleMock(&argc, arvg);
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();

}
```

Contudo, nem mesmo esse código compila e obtenho o seguinte erro:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
Compiling 'main.cpp' ...
/snap/clion/37/bin/cmake/linux/bin/cmake --build /home/renan/CLionProjects/Testing/cmake-build-debug --target CMakeFiles/Testing.dir/main.cpp.o -- -j 2 -f /home/renan/CLionProjects/Testing/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/Testing.dir/build.make --always-make
Building CXX object CMakeFiles/Testing.dir/main.cpp.o
In file included from /home/renan/CLionProjects/Testing/lib/googletest-master/googlemock/include/gmock/gmock-spec-builders.h:71:0,
                 from /home/renan/CLionProjects/Testing/lib/googletest-master/googlemock/include/gmock/gmock-generated-function-mockers.h:44,
                 from /home/renan/CLionProjects/Testing/lib/googletest-master/googlemock/include/gmock/gmock.h:62,
                 from /home/renan/CLionProjects/Testing/main.cpp:2:
/home/renan/CLionProjects/Testing/lib/googletest-master/googlemock/include/gmock/gmock-matchers.h:842:11: error: invalid use of template-name ‘testing::Matcher’ without an argument list
     const Matcher A();
           ^~~~~~~
/home/renan/CLionProjects/Testing/lib/googletest-master/googlemock/include/gmock/gmock-matchers.h:842:11: note: class template argument deduction is only available with -std=c++1z or -std=gnu++1z
In file included from /home/renan/CLionProjects/Testing/lib/googletest-master/googlemock/include/gmock/internal/gmock-internal-utils.h:45:0,
                 from /home/renan/CLionProjects/Testing/lib/googletest-master/googlemock/include/gmock/gmock-actions.h:47,
                 from /home/renan/CLionProjects/Testing/lib/googletest-master/googlemock/include/gmock/gmock.h:59,
                 from /home/renan/CLionProjects/Testing/main.cpp:2:
/home/renan/CLionProjects/Testing/lib/googletest-master/googlemock/include/gmock/internal/gmock-generated-internal-utils.h:50:7: note: ‘template<class T> class testing::Matcher’ declared here
 class Matcher;
       ^~~~~~~
In file included from /home/renan/CLionProjects/Testing/lib/googletest-master/googlemock/include/gmock/gmock-spec-builders.h:71:0,
                 from /home/renan/CLionProjects/Testing/lib/googletest-master/googlemock/include/gmock/gmock-generated-function-mockers.h:44,
                 from /home/renan/CLionProjects/Testing/lib/googletest-master/googlemock/include/gmock/gmock.h:62,
                 from /home/renan/CLionProjects/Testing/main.cpp:2:
/home/renan/CLionProjects/Testing/lib/googletest-master/googlemock/include/gmock/gmock-matchers.h: In member function ‘testing::internal::AnythingMatcher::operator testing::Matcher<A1>() const’:
/home/renan/CLionProjects/Testing/lib/googletest-master/googlemock/include/gmock/gmock-matchers.h:1052:40: error: ‘A’ was not declared in this scope
   operator Matcher<T>() const { return A<T>(); }
```

Gostaria que alguém me desse uma luz sobre o que estou fazendo de errado nos meus [testes](https://github.com/RenanCbcc/Testing.git). Grato.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Após horas batendo cabeça, resolvi o problema simplesmente alterando o `CMakeLists.txt` na raiz do projeto de:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)
project(Testing)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

add_executable(Testing main.cpp domain/Auction.cpp domain/Auction.h domain/User.cpp domain/User.h domain/Bid.cpp domain/Bid.h service/Evaluator.cpp service/Evaluator.h builder/TestBuilder.cpp builder/TestBuilder.h domain/Payment.cpp domain/Payment.h persistence/FakeAuctionDAO.cpp persistence/FakeAuctionDAO.h persistence/AuctionDAO.cpp persistence/AuctionDAO.h service/Finisher.cpp service/Finisher.h)
add_subdirectory(lib/googletest-master)
include_directories(lib/googletest-master/googletest/include)
include_directories(lib/googletest-master/googlemock/include)
target_link_libraries(Testing gtest gtest_main)
```

para:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)
project(Testing)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

add_subdirectory(lib/googletest-master)
include_directories(lib/googletest-master/googletest/include)
include_directories(lib/googletest-master/googlemock/include)

add_executable(Testing main.cpp domain/Auction.cpp domain/Auction.h domain/User.cpp domain/User.h domain/Bid.cpp domain/Bid.h service/Evaluator.cpp service/Evaluator.h builder/TestBuilder.cpp builder/TestBuilder.h domain/Payment.cpp domain/Payment.h persistence/FakeAuctionDAO.cpp persistence/FakeAuctionDAO.h persistence/AuctionDAO.cpp persistence/AuctionDAO.h service/Finisher.h service/Finisher.cpp)

target_link_libraries(Testing gtest gtest_main)
target_link_libraries(Testing gmock gmock_main)
```

E isso resolveu o meu problema.